# Why does mounting s3fs bucket on CentOS 7 using fstab fail, but 'mount -a' works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, centos7, s3fs, fstab

I have a CentOS 7 instance where I'm mounting an S3 bucket. I can mount it successfully with the s3fs command, but my fstab entries do not work. However, after I boot I can run 'mount -a' and the buckets mount normally. The entry looks like this:

`bucketname /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/cr fuse.s3fs _netdev,allow_other,umask=000 0 0`

I see this in /var/log/messages:

```
May 29 14:07:59 adoring mount: s3fs: BUCKET /bucketname -- bucket name contains an illegal character.
```

Obviously, it doesn't *really* contain an illegal character, as it works with 'mount -a'. What could be going on here?

I expect the bucket to mount normally.

Comment: Can you share the bucket name?  It should not contain any of the following characters: /:\\;!@#$%^&*?|+=